# Multi document transaction in MongoDB - Book & Author example

Tags: java, mongodb, transactions, mongodb-java

I am new to MongoDB and as a learning exercise I am developing a Library Management System using Java in MongoDB. The problem I have encountered is, how to ensure Transaction properties in the following scenario :

I have a Book class and an Author class, which have many-to-many relationship. Now when I am saving a specific book, it may have multiple authors. I am saving/updating the Authors first including a generated Book ID, then I am saving the Book class with the Author ID(s). Now, how can I ensure this multi-document save follows transaction properties?

Searching through previous posts I got a [Two Phase Commit plan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) as given in MongoDB website, but it is unclear to me how I could use that method in my application.

Untill now, I have made "rollback" and "commit" alternative by shadow backup of documents, but in the long run this is not feasible as it doubles the database size. Also, I would like to know why MongoDB doesn't have an in-built method to handle transactions.

Comment: Tbh no matter how much you fake it client side MongoDB has no multi document transactions, making it have them is not a good learning exercise, instead you should learn to embrace eventual consistentcy

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know why MongoDB doesn't have an in-built method to handle transactions.

Transactions are hard. I think there are three arguments of why one can live without them:

1. In SQL, transactions are extremely important because you're breaking up objects. An invoice doesn't have line items in SQL, but the line items reference the invoice. So having a partial commit could lead to an invoice with half the line items missing (but everything apparently working). Since MongoDB supports embedding, you don't need to split up *all* objects and the need for joins and transactions is much less severe (though, in general, be careful about embedding).
2. DB transactions are nice, but it's fairly common to need *business transactions*, i.e. a much longer running operation that might have to wait for API calls, user interaction, etc. This logic, including the logic of rolling back such a transaction must be handled in application code.
3. Scalability: Transactions are tricky on a single machine, but they are brutal in a sharded and replicated environment. You'd have to have a transaction coordinator that sits somewhere, waits until everything is finished and returns or eventually calls it a quit and sends a rollback. Now image there's a network partition or the transaction coordinator goes down... All this is hard to implement and chews performance. It also hides a severe amount of complexity from  developers. Again, it's best to handle this in application code, or use other strategies such as [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) (Multiversion concurrency control).